# blazorserver.js and some other static files not loading in localization

Tags: localization, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-localization

I am working on a blazor server app on .net 6 and in that I have implemented localization from the microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0).
Also added mudblazor for UI

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIJIn.png)
Program.js
localization implementation

```
builder.Services.AddLocalization(opt => opt.ResourcesPath = LocalizationConstants.ResourcesPath);


var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions().SetDefaultCulture(LocalizationConstants.SupportedLanguages.Select(x => x.Code).First())
          .AddSupportedCultures(LocalizationConstants.SupportedLanguages.Select(x => x.Code).ToArray())
          .AddSupportedUICultures(LocalizationConstants.SupportedLanguages.Select(x => x.Code).ToArray());

app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

Here I am passing the 2 languages English and Arabic using a class so that code is not hardcoded

I have created a component for selecting the Culture same as given in Microsoft documentation

```
@using System.Globalization
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<select @bind="Culture" class="form-select form-select-sm" style="width:fit-content">
    @foreach (var culture in supportedCultures)
    {
        <option class="form-control" value="@culture">@culture.DisplayName</option>
    }
</select>


@code
{
    private CultureInfo[] supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("ar-iq"),
        new CultureInfo("zh-Hans")
    };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    private CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
        set
        {
            if (CultureInfo.CurrentCulture != value)
            {
                var uri = new Uri(Navigation.Uri).GetComponents(UriComponents.PathAndQuery, UriFormat.Unescaped);
                var cultureEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(value.Name);
                var uriEscaped = Uri.EscapeDataString(uri);
                Navigation.NavigateTo($"Culture/Set?culture={cultureEscaped}&redirectUri={uriEscaped}", forceLoad: true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And at last there is a controller which sets the language selected in the cookie so that the state of language selected stays in subsequent requests(also copied from documentation)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class CultureController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Set(string culture, string redirectUri)
        {
            if (culture != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
                    CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(
                        new RequestCulture(culture, culture)));
            }

            return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Localization Implementation

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<App> L

<MudText Typo="Typo.h4" Color="Color.Primary" Class="pt-5">@L["Dashboard"]</MudText>
```

So when I try to change the language in a page like this - https://localhost:7184/dashboard. There is no issue it works fine but when I try in page like https://localhost:7184/dashboard/Add or like this - https://localhost:7184/dashboard/Edit or https://localhost:7184/dashboard/Add/Count the blazorserver.js and other static files do not load and the UI breaks

I tried debugging the values come fine till the end but it breaks some how and I am not sure what the issue is over here